# CS5001 C# Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point

Tags: c#

hello im trying to make my app work. Windows forms app (.NET Framework)
when i started it didnt create a class Program.cs and now it says that error: CS5001 C# Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point.
How do i fix this?

```
    namespace thingy
    { 

        class Program
        {
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: BTW. This is pretty good illustration of problems with *main* (especially public and static): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P4ZAt4wuHUg

Comment: i did this and when i open my app it opens and closes

    namespace thingy
    {
    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {

        }
    }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally your Program.cs class should look like this:

```
 public static class Program
 {
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main()
    {
       // open your form here
       Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
```

Comment: i did this and when i open my app it opens and closes

Comment: @SoaZ you need to open your form as well

Comment: ohhhhh ok thanks mate!!! i forgot i think i deleted it by accident ! :DD

Comment: @SoaZ you can also mark my answer as correct ;)

Answer (score 0):

Technically, to remove this specific error you need

```
public static void Main() 
{
 ...
}
```

but something went wrong in the process of creating the app. I think you should start from scratch.

You could follow [Create a Windows Forms app in Visual Studio with C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/create-csharp-winform-visual-studio?view=vs-2022).

Comment: i did this and when i open my app it opens and closes